# Ошибка в переданном параметре функции

Tags: javascript, функции, select, onchange

В 3й раз передаю в  функцию селект и  массив(первые  два раза   всё нормально)  и получаю ошибку... через console.log  вместо списка городов получаю undefinded

```js
let data={
    Russia:['Moscow','Petersburg','Yekaterinburg'],
    USA:['New York', 'California', 'Seattle'],
    Germany:['Berlin', 'Munich', 'Cologne'],
    England:['London', 'York', 'Birmingham'],
    France:['Paris','Strasbourg','Nice']

}
let citiesSelect=document.querySelector('#cities')
let countriesSelect=document.querySelector('#countries')

let countries=Object.keys(data) // добавим страны начиная  с 1 в массиве коючей
    console.log(countries)
addOption(countriesSelect,countries)

let defaultCities=data[countries[0]] //город по дефолту,1й из 1го массива значений
console.log(defaultCities)
addOption(citiesSelect,defaultCities)

countriesSelect.addEventListener('change',()=>{
let cities=data[this.value] // массив городов,для выбранной страны
    console.log(cities)
    citiesSelect.length=0
    addOption(citiesSelect,cities)
})

function addOption(select,arr){
    for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        select.add(new Option(arr[i],arr[i]))
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <select id="countries"></select>
    <select id="cities"></select>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: А что у вас в this.value? Может там ключ который не установлен в data?

Comment: mego4iter  целиком объект вверху не влез
let data={
    Russia:['Moscow','Petersburg','Yekaterinburg'],
    USA:['New York', 'California', 'Seattle'],
    Germany:['Berlin', 'Munich', 'Cologne'],
    England:['London', 'York', 'Birmingham'],
    France:['Paris','Strasbourg','Nice']
}

Comment: а чему равно this.value когда cities undefined?
могу предположить что у option в select не проставляется аттрибут value

Comment: *"По этим картинкам, по этим картинкам, которые мы рисовали для вас, Придумайте сами, придумайте сами, придумайте сами веселый рассказ."*

Comment: Igor  ну и как? Придумали? Сомневаюсь, что вы за  этим сюда пришли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас Option создаётся с названием и без значения.
Попробуйте так

```
select.app(new Option(arr[i], arr[i]))
```

[Option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option)

`this` в калбэке на `change` указывает не на `select`
нужно использовать объект `event`

```
countriesSelect.addEventListener('change',(event)=>{
let cities=data[event.target.value]
```

Comment: Не помогло. Дело  не  в Option,  последний переданный массив не   проходит через функцию addOption.. у него даже Length   вывести не получается в консоль

Comment: Может тогда пример кода вставить? Было бы проще разобраться с проблемой...

Comment: Код вставил, странно что скрины никому не нравятся

Comment: @ZdraviSmisl подразобрался, дополнил ответ
вот на сколько код упростил решение)

Comment: Спасибо вам! Конечно.. ошибка  смешная).  this.value  в стрелочной функции писать, это успех определённо)